# Pushing elements of the vector to the left

Tags: c++, vector

31 04 00 08

Suppose this is the input vector file:

How do I generate this?

31 48 00 00

I want to push all the non-zero numbers from '04' to the left. Help please!!

Comment: There is a `std::rotate` function.

Comment: @ron I want another alternative

Comment: That's likely the *ideal* solution. You could always enumerate with a copy_if and a back-inserter to another string, then back-fill with the contrapositive to your copy_if conditional. That would not be ideal, nor space efficient, but would nonetheless work. Now, what have you tried so far, and where does it seem to be failing?

Comment: @WhozCraig Is std::rotate a C++ 11 feature?

Comment: It's been there since C++98.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in a single pass through the vector with the following:

```
vector<int> v = {3, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 8};
auto zero_iter = find(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
for (auto curr_iter = zero_iter; curr_iter != v.end(); curr_iter++) {
    if (*curr_iter != 0) {
        swap(*curr_iter, *zero_iter);
        zero_iter++;
    }
}
```

This uses `std::find` and `std::swap` from `<algorithm>`.

---

The idea here is to keep track of where the first available zero location is, and find the non-zero locations after that. Every time a non-zero number is found, you swap it into the first available zero location and increment your zero location to point to the next spot.

Answer (score 1):

At least in my opinion, the solutions that have been given so far fall somewhat short of ideal.

The standard library provides an algorithm designed specifically for the task at hand. You're trying to partition the input into non-zero numbers followed by zeros. For that, `std::stable_partition` will work beautifully:

```
std::string input = "31040008";

std::stable_partition(input.begin(), input.end(),
    [](auto c) { return c != '0'; });
```

Result:

```
31480000
```

If you don't care about the order of the non-zero numbers (just that they all precede the zeros) you can probably gain a little speed by using `std::partition` instead.

Comment: Perfect indeed, deserves upvote

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::remove` to remove all 0s. Well in fact it will just push all elements which are not zero to the left and return the start of the portion you want to erase. But instead of erasing you can just fill it with 0s:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 3, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 8 };
    std::fill(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 0), v.end(), 0);


    //test
    for (auto d : v)
        std::cout << d << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
3 1 4 8 0 0 0 0
```